# Accessing values from another model without creating field in current model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `Issue` and `ProductionReport`. I want to create a form with fields both for `Issue` and `ProductionReport`. The values for `Issues` would come from database and the values for `ProductionReport` are new. And finally when the user clicks on submit button all the values should get stored in `ProductionReport` table. I have the following controller:

```
 def index_productionReport
   @issue = Issue.all
   @issue = Issue.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:10).order("created_at DESC")
 end

 def add_productionReport
   @production_report=ProductionReport.new
   @issue=Issue.find(params[:id])
 end

 def get_production
   @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
   @production_report = ProductionReport.new(production_report_params)
   @production_report.save
   flash[:notice] = "production Saved Successfully!!!"
   redirect_to :action => "index_productionReport"
 end
```

And my view is:

```
<%= form_for @production_report, :url=>{:controller=>"users",:action=>"get_production" } do |i|%>
<%= fields_for @issue do |i| %>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :order_no,:required => true,:autofocus=>true %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :issue_slip_no,:required => true %></td></tr>
<%end%>
<tr><td><%= i.label  :finished_goods_name,"finished goods name"%></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :finished_goods_name,:required => true %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.label  :total_no_of_items_produced,"total no of item"%></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :total_no_of_items_produced,:required => true  %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.label  :weight_per_item,"weight per item" %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :weight_per_item,:required => true %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.label  :total_weight_consumed,"total weight consumed" %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :total_weight_consumed,:required => true %></td></tr>
<%= i.submit "save" %>
<%end%>
```

Someone please help me to achieve my need..

UPDATE:
Flow:
I have the list of issues at index_productionReport with link for "add" at each issues. When the user clicks on add, the add_productionRepor will appear with 2 values from Issue table and the remaining empty fields are for ProductionReport. Now when the user clicks on save button, All the values should get stored in ProductionReport Table.

Comment: Why would you use user input fields for values (@issue) that you read from the db? You want to save the `@issue` values `order_no`and `issue_slip_no` together with user input in `@production_report`? How does your `production_report_params`method look like?

Comment: def production_report_params
      params.require(:production_report).permit!
    end

Comment: The user should view the order_no and issue_slip_no of the Issue model before entering the values for ProductionReport.. All the values from Issue model will be in readonly mode @Flip

Comment: Then why using input fields and not just printing them on the screen? As for the params method: I never used `permit!`, have you tried `params.require(:production_report).permit(:finished_goods_name, :total_no_of_items_produced, :weight_per_item, :total_weight_consumed)`

Comment: I want the fields from Issue model to get stored along with the fields of ProductionReport.This is my main issue..

Comment: Where do you want to store them? In the production report?

Comment: yes.. I want all those to get stored in ProductionReport table.. @Flip

Comment: I think I would create a production report object as soon as I have the two issue values you want to be saved in the report, and then have a form updating the production report rather than creating it. But it's hard to say as you don't say what exactly the workflow should be like. Where does @issue  come from?

Comment: Do you have columns for the issue attributes in the ProductionReport table? If not, create them, and define normal text input fields for them in your view, that you prefill with the value you get from the respective attributes in your @issue..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, it looks like `ProductionReport` belongs to `Issue` and the `Issue` can have many `ProductionReport`s. In which case, I would store the `issue_id` in the `production_reports` table, which is considered a normalized way, rather than some info (`order_no` and `issue_slip_no`), which is considered a de-normalized way.

Whatever the information I need from `Issue` for a given `ProductionReport`, I can directly query from `Issue`. For example: `@production_report.issue.order_no` or `@production_report.issue.issue_slip_no`. If you want to hide the implementation details, you could even delegate `order_no` and `issue_slip_no` as well, as follows:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :production_reports
end

class ProductionReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue

  delegate :order_no, :issue_slip_no, :to => :issue
end
```

The `de-normalized way` causes duplication, which leads to data consistency. Imagine, some one updates the `order_no` and `issue_slip_no` of the `Issue`, after the `ProductionReport` is created. They both contain two different information.

Nevertheless, if you need to store `order_no` and `issue_slip_no` from `Issue` directly in the `ProductionReport`, due to some other business requirements, you could use the following for your view:

```
<%= form_for @production_report, :url=>{:controller=>"users", :action=>"get_production" } do |i|%>
  <tr><td><%= i.text_field :order_no, :required => true, :readonly => true, value => @issue.order_no, :autofocus=>true %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.text_field :issue_slip_no, :readonly => true, value => @issue.issue_slip_no, :required => true %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.label :finished_goods_name, "finished goods name" %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.text_field :finished_goods_name, :required => true %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.label :total_no_of_items_produced,"total no of item" %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.text_field :total_no_of_items_produced,:required => true  %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.label :weight_per_item,"weight per item" %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.text_field :weight_per_item,:required => true %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.label :total_weight_consumed,"total weight consumed" %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><%= i.text_field :total_weight_consumed,:required => true %></td></tr>
  <%= i.submit "save" %>
<%end%>
```

Finally, instead of shoving all the actions into `UsersController`, I would follow the following separation:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # include actions pertain to users model
end

class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @issue = Issue.all
    @issue = @issue.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:10)
    @issue = @issue.order("created_at DESC")
  end
end

class ProductionReportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
    # if you were to use belongs_to and has_many design, I mentioned above
    @production_report = @issue.production_reports.build
    # or not 
    @production_report = ProductionReport.new
  end

  def create
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
    # if you were to use belongs_to and has_many design, I mentioned above
    @production_report = @issue.production_reports.build(production_report_params)
    # or not
    @production_report = ProductionReport.new(production_report_params)

    if @production_report.save
      flash[:notice] = "production Saved Successfully!!!"
      redirect_to issues_url
    else
      # logic for failed save, repopulate the form with validation errors
    end    
  end
end
```